# Data stream clustering using scikit-multiflow

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-stream

I have a CSV file data set as follows and I wrote my stream clustering algorithm. I wanna generate stream data to simulate the process. I found scikit-multiflow. I have a question that how can I do this? Now I pretend and use row by row.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, Scikit-multiflow does not support clustering yet.